# Where to configure routes and paths in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Probably a noob question but I'm new to Rails and building my first app as a project to complete my apprenticeship.

I have four pages listing contact, account, billing plan and call information. Each have that standard edit, show and create functions.

I have a table that pulls information from FreeAgent using the API, It just lists basic information (price, due date etc.) I want to create another page so when the user clicks on the invoice they go to another page containing a PDF and more information.

So instead of the path being /accounts/'user id' I want it to be /accounts/'user id'/invoice

Do I need to create another controller or just define a new method in the accounts controller?

Cheers
Arran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the [RoR Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) first, especially the [section on nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Your routes in `routes.rb` probably look something like this:

```
resources :accounts
resources :invoices
```

The aforementioned guide will teach you that you should define the routes like this instead:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :invoices
end
```

which will give you these routes

```
verb  route                               action
------------------------------------------------
GET   /accounts/:account_id/invoices      index
GET   /accounts/:account_id/invoices/new  new
POST  /accounts/:account_id/invoices      create
GET   /accounts/:account_id/invoices/:id  show
```

and so on ...